# How to create a table from list elements in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, text, element

started with PDF -> .txt. Then appended the lines into a list.

I'm now stuck. How would I go about creating each "string" as its own element. I thought about replacing the whitespace with '/n', but the attribute,. .replace(), is for strings only.

Here is a sample of my INPUT (.txt) file. There are three lines. The '---' is the 2nd line and any line after a dash line is what I want to grab. I'm thinking about manipulating the string before appending to line_nu.

```
Item      Material/Description  Contract Delivery Date              
Total Qty   UM                 Net Price       Extended Amount
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------------------------------
     1    1TD1131D17025-2035    09/16/2022      2     EA     353.60        707.20 
SHEAR PANEL
```

HERE is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import string

PO = open('5000298001-Original.txt','r',encoding = 'utf8')

line_text = enumerate(PO.readlines())

PO.seek(0)

count = PO.readlines()[2]

PO.seek(0)


line_nu = []
for i, line in line_text:
    if count == line:
        next_count = i +1
        next_line = PO.readlines()[next_count]
        line_nu.append(next_line)
        PO.seek(0)
```

This is my current output:

```
['    1        1TD1131D17025-2035              09/16/2022                              
2     EA                       353.60                         
707.20 \n', '    2        1TD1131D17025-2036              
09/16/2022                              2     EA                       
353.60                         707.20 \n', '    3        
1TD1131D17025-2037              09/16/2022                              
2     EA                       353.60                         
707.20 \n']
```

This is the DataFrame i'm trying to get:

```
item   part               ship_date   qty   PP      EP
1     1TD1131D17025-2035  09/16/2022  2   353.60  707.20
2     1TD1131D17025-2036  09/16/2022  2   353.60  707.20   
3     1TD1131D17025-2037  09/16/2022  2   353.60  707.20
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please edit this post to include text of the code you have tried, the input you are starting from and the output you expect. Only include text, not pictures.

Comment: I assume that what you mean by your current output is the value of `nu_line`. What do you get if you add the following at the end? `line_nu = [line.split(' ') for line in nu_line]`